# Ext.Net tabs and message bus

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I am creating an Ext.Net project and I have used the group tab panel in the link 
: http://examples.ext.net/#/TabPanel/GroupTabPanel/Overview/

The first thing is I want to add a new tab on each click of the sub menus .. 
Also I want to be able to use the messages broadcasted from previous tabs using the message bus in these created tabs.

I am very lost here... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The MessageBus samples in the Ext.NET Examples Explorer might help get you started, see

http://examples.ext.net/#/search/MessageBus

Other than that, your post is a little thin on details, so I'm not sure what else to recommend.

Comment: I want be able to make the newly added tab listens to the broadcasted message from the previous tab .. the thing is adding a new tab with a loader in that tab doesn't listens to anything I have to broadcast the message again to be able to listen to it in the newly added tab... I have used the example http://examples.ext.net/#/search/MessageBus here in my message bus

Comment: FYI: this conversation was also started in the Ext.NET forums (http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?21435-Ext-net-message-bus-and-tabs) and continues there for now. I'll try to remember to post the answer/sample here once thread has been solved.